# Changing maven snapshot timestamp

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

When deploying a snapshot file to a maven repository, I want to be able to control the timestamp that is being used in the resulting file name, right now I see something like this show up:

`/snapshots/com/exampleinc/example/0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/example-0.0.0-20190224.230223-37.jar`

I want to be able to set `20190224.230223` when running `mvn deploy`.

I tried setting `maven.build.timestamp` however it had no effect on it.

I can't find any documentation on how to do this, and I am not sure about which bit of code is actually controlling this so can't just dig through it.

The reason behind wanting to set this value is I want that timestamp embedded in the manifest file so that we can read it within the java process & associate it back to the original file without needing to read each jar (as there could be hundreds of builds for the same snapshot version)

Comment: The timestamp in the MANIFEST.MF is different from the timestamp created during the deployment of artifacts. In short you can't change the timestamp of the files..you can change the MANIFEST.MF entry as already answered.

Answer (score 3):

Build `timestamp` can be customized by declaring the property `maven.build.timestamp.format`, you can find the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables)

```
<properties>
  <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

We write a "build number" to a properties file in the jar (MANIFEST.MF would work as well) which represents the last part of the created jar name (`37` in your case).

With this information, it is possible to uniquely identify the jar, e.g. by questioning Nexus for the list of all timestamps for a given SNAPSHOT and extract the correct one.